# NSMutableURLRequest with "=" char in parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have to post parameters to an url and i have a parameter that has a "=" char so I should escape it. Here attach what I'm doing in objective-C.

```
for (NSString* key in json) {
    NSString *current = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@",key,[json objectForKey:key]];
    [post appendString: current];

}
//so post has this style: "&password=eodhxgkpo=&usuario=user1"      
NSURL *urlObj = [NSURL URLWithString: itemAddress];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: urlObj];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[post UTF8String] length:[post length]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

[webView loadRequest: request];
```

this same code works if password has no "=" char. So there is any way to escape this kind of chars?

(the content-type has to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Thanks for your help

Danilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the list of escapes codes for URL here:

http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

You have to use %3D for escaping =

Hope it helps!

Comment: This solution worked.. Thanks! I also wrote a blog post where is showed the code I used to solve the problem: http://ddelizia.blogspot.com/2012/03/ios-dev-post-parameters-to-url-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
// path is a NSString
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```